# Why more than one chromosome in an organism?

Tags: genomics, chromosome

Why not one chromosome to house genome in organisms but multiple?
Is it for epigenomic purposes?

Comment: Are you asking about [ploidy number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ploidy) or chromosome number? Do you have any reason for expecting every organism ro only have a single chromosome? Why did you suggest epigenetics? What are your thoughts?

Comment: I am asking about the chromosome number. I ask this because the chromosome numbers are not the same across different organism and I feel there could be a reason for this. I suggest epigenetics because of the need for histones to interact with genomic sequence for modulation of genes.

Comment: The problem here is in attributing purpose to evolution, when it's a series of accidents, some of which survived.  There are a number of things that can cause chromosomes to be duplicated. (Colchicine is commonly used in modern plant breeding.)  If an organsm has its single chromosome accidentally duplicated, and the offspring survive, that change gets propagated to ensuing generations...

Comment: @jamesqf Then why do we have different genes on different chromosomes and not duplicates?

Comment: @Atajera If a chromosome were duplicated, for it to stay a duplicate and not diverge, every change would have to happen at the same time to every chromosome. That's not really feasible.

Comment: @BryanKrause That explains the duplicity, how about the change to different but essential genes. Why not essential genes only on the parent chromosome if the theory is true?

Comment: @Atajera What mechanism do you propose that would cause genes to only change on one chromosome once there is more than one?

Comment: I seem to remember a related question in relation to maximum chromosome size. Those interested might do worse than look for it.

Comment: @Atajera: Understand that I am only guessing/making logical deductions here, but once you have two chromosomes, each will undergo random mutations, some of which will prove beneficial.  Carry that process on long enough, and the organism now has two different chromosomes, potentially carrying twice as much information.  (It also seems as though copying one long chromosome would be less efficient and more error-prone than  several short ones.)

Comment: @jamesqf: I agree with your theory

Comment: @BryanKrause: None but what I meant was that the change occurs in both but results in two different essential gene but not two variants of the same gene.